# Como excluir arquivos não acessíveis da pasta TEMPORÁRIA do windows com uma aplicação C#

Tags: c#

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmfmr.png)

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação com C# para excluir arquivos e subpastas do diretorio do windows onde fica a pasta temp (C:\Users\Administrador\AppData\Local\Temp), onde consigo realizar com qualquer outra pasta mas somente esta não devido a ter arquivos que não foi possivel encontrar ou excluir.
[gostaria de saber por favor como contornar este erro e assim conseguir excluir os demais arquivos que tenho nesta pasta caso alguns não sejam encontrados. Ja nao sei por onde mais procurar ou algum artigo que me auxilie.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idY0q.png)
Desde ja muito obrigado.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jx0Y.png)

Comment: Tenta abrir o Visual Studio como Administrador. Clicar com o botão direito no atalho do VS e "Executar como Administrador".

Comment: É um arquivo temporário que deve estar em uso por alguma aplicação ou pelo sistema.

Comment: tudo bem entendi, mas quero pular este arquivo e dar continuidade. Passar para os próximos, pois aparece o erro e para somente ai e nao da continuidade. Tem mais arquivos e o erro aparece e nao e tratado para dar continuidade. e isso que eu estou precisando, dar continuidade tratando ou ignorando o erro de arquivo sendo utilizado.

Comment: @JosimarMarcos coloque a exclusão do arquivo dentro de um bloco `try` e dentro manipulador de exceções de um `continue`. PS: Não vou responder a essa pergunta porque o código foi apensado como imagem. Leia [O Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas | Não publicar código como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485)

Comment: O Ricardo pela dica e orientação, não tinha me atentado para forma de uso. Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Como quer pular o arquivo e dar continuidade, coloque a instrução dentro de um bloco try..catch:

```
try {
    fi.Delete();
} catch { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você precisa abrir a aplicação como administrador, então faça os seguintes passos:

- Clique em Projeto - Adicionar novo item - selecione Arquivo de manifesto (somente windows)

Em seguida, será gerado um arquivo de manifesto em seu projeto, cujo nome é `app.manifest`.

- Agora, entre em seu arquivo de manifesto e procure pela linha escrita `<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />` e troque o `asInvoker` por `requireAdministrator`

Ficando assim: `<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />`

Agora, clique em `Iniciar` para o Visual Studio reiniciar ele e abrir com mais privilégios, executando seu aplicativo como Administrador.

Agora faça os testes. :)